# Syntax error: Expected ")" but got "(" [at 1:79] While Executing Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I try to run this SQL query:

```
WITH is_positive AS (SELECT x>0 FROM UNNEST([5, -2, 3, 6, -10, -7, 4, 0]) AS t(x))
SELECT COUNTIF(is_positive);
```

but I get an error

> Syntax error: Expected ")" but got "(" [at 1:79]

Can you help me to figure out where the problem is?

Where to test: https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=root-melody-302907

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below fixed version

```
WITH is_positive AS (
    SELECT x > 0 flag
    FROM UNNEST([5, -2, 3, 6, -10, -7, 4, 0]) AS x
)
SELECT COUNTIF(flag)
FROM is_positive
```